# Undefined variable for a second query

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have an undefined Variable problem:

Effect on this first part of code everything works my variable $ id and well defined and works fine.

The cell_id is the result of a combobox which is then transmitted as an ajax on this page and it works fine

```
if(isset($_GET['cellule_id']) && !empty($_GET['cellule_id'])){
include('../../../connexion.php');

$id= $_GET['cellule_id'];



$query1 = pg_query($db,'SELECT ("T_CELLULE"."IDLocationEnCoursCellule"), COUNT(*) as qte_att_m
                        FROM "T_STATUT", "T_STATUT_CELLULE", "T_CELLULE", "T_OF"
                        WHERE ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."SNCellule")=("T_CELLULE"."SNCellule")
                        AND ("T_STATUT"."IDStatut")=("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."IDStatut")
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."OF")=("T_CELLULE"."OF")
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."IDProcess")=("T_CELLULE"."IDProcess")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."OF"="T_OF"."OF")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."IDProcess"="T_OF"."IDProcess")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."RebutCellule" Is Null)
                        AND NOT("T_CELLULE"."IDLocationEnCoursCellule" Is Null)
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."FinProcess" Is Null) 
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."EnCours"=True)
                        AND ("T_STATUT"."IDStatut") = 2
                        AND ("T_OF"."TypeCellule")= \''. $id. '\'
                        GROUP BY "IDLocationEnCoursCellule"');
```

But when I want to display the result of my query in a js chart using google charts the problem comes from my query which is exactly the same but this time the $ id is not defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['IDLocationEnCoursCellule','qte_att_m'],
          <?php
          $result = pg_query($db,'SELECT ("T_CELLULE"."IDLocationEnCoursCellule"), COUNT(*) as qte_att_m
                        FROM "T_STATUT", "T_STATUT_CELLULE", "T_CELLULE", "T_OF"
                        WHERE ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."SNCellule")=("T_CELLULE"."SNCellule")
                        AND ("T_STATUT"."IDStatut")=("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."IDStatut")
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."OF")=("T_CELLULE"."OF")
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."IDProcess")=("T_CELLULE"."IDProcess")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."OF"="T_OF"."OF")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."IDProcess"="T_OF"."IDProcess")
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."RebutCellule" Is Null)
                        AND NOT("T_CELLULE"."IDLocationEnCoursCellule" Is Null)
                        AND ("T_CELLULE"."FinProcess" Is Null) 
                        AND ("T_STATUT_CELLULE"."EnCours"=True)
                        AND ("T_STATUT"."IDStatut") = 2
                        AND ("T_OF"."TypeCellule")= \''. $id. '\'
                        GROUP BY "IDLocationEnCoursCellule"');
           
            while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "['".$row['IDLocationEnCoursCellule']."',".$row['qte_att_m']."],";
 
            } 
          ?>
        ]);
 
        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'test graphique',
            subtitle: 'sous titre du test graphique',
          }
        };
 
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
 
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
    <div id="columnchart_material"></div>
```

If I replace my $ id variable with a hard element it works but I have an undefined variable error

I tried a multitude of things:

```
- to put the $id= $_GET['cellule_id'];in the php just before my request
```

I've been there for 7 days on it

I can't figure out how a variable can be defined 30 lines above and then undefined thereafter.

thank you in advance good week everyone

leo